# React Slick slider, current active slide overlapped by next slide

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel, slick.js

I'm currently using Slick in order to make a carousel.

I'm having two issues right now, let's start with the first one.

**1)**

I'm currently using a slider in which i want to show 3 slides: the current image (Spyro), the previous one (Crash) and the next one (Tekken).
[image: Problem with carousel]

As you see, while the current slide correctly overlaps the previous one (Spyro > Crash), the next one overlaps the current slide (Tekken > Spyro).

**Of course i want the current slide to be on top of both of them... How can i fix this?**

I'm attacching the code below.

***App.js***

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import SliderData from "./SliderData";

import { AiOutlineArrowLeft, AiOutlineArrowRight } from "react-icons/ai";

function useWindowSize() {
  const [size, setSize] = useState([window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => setSize([window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth]);
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, [])
  return size;
}


const array = SliderData.map((x) => {
  return x.image;
})

console.log(array);

function App() {
  const NextArrow = ({ onClick }) => {
    return (
      <div className="arrow next" onClick={onClick}>
        <AiOutlineArrowRight />
      </div>
    );
  };

  const PrevArrow = ({ onClick }) => {
    return (
      <div className="arrow prev" onClick={onClick}>
        <AiOutlineArrowLeft />
      </div>
    );
  };

  const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);

  const [height, width] = useWindowSize();

  const settings = {
    className: "center",
    infinite: true,
    lazyLoad: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: width > 1000 ? 3: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: "60px",
    nextArrow: <NextArrow />,
    prevArrow: <PrevArrow />,
    beforeChange: (current, next) => {
      console.log(current);
      setImageIndex(next);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Slider {...settings}>
          {array.map((img, idx) => (
            <div className={idx === imageIndex ? "slide activeSlide" : "slide"}>
              <img src={img} alt={img} />
            </div>
          ))}
        </Slider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***App.css***

```
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

.App {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10rem auto;
  height: 570px;
}

.slide img {
  width: 35rem;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: transform 300ms;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}

.activeSlide {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  align-items: center;
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

.arrow svg {
  transition: color 300ms;
}

.arrow svg:hover {
  color: #68edff;
}

.next {
  right: 3%;
  top: 50%;
}

.prev {
  left: 3%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

***SliderData.js***

```
const SliderData = [
  {
    image:
      "https://www.spaziogames.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Crash-4-Pirate_06-29-20.jpg"
  },
  {
    image:
      "https://d2skuhm0vrry40.cloudfront.net/2018/articles/2018-07-18-14-24/news-videogiochi-spyro-reignited-trilogy-video-di-gameplay-livello-colossus-1531920251281.jpg/EG11/thumbnail/750x422/format/jpg/quality/60"
  },
  {
    image: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OUh82pOFGDU/maxresdefault.jpg"
  },
  {
    image: "https://www.psu.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/MetalGearSolidRemake-1024x576.jpg"
  }
];

export default SliderData;
```

---

**2)**

As you see, the active slide is not perfectly centered. Since i suck in CSS i did not use the `display: flex;` command.
What do you suggest? how can i fix this?

Thank you all.

Comment: try adding `z-index: 2` to the `.activeSlide` css class. Issue might be bacuse all your slides are stacked at the same z-index.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: can you do the same for `.activeSlide img{}` and check once. `z-index: 2`.

Comment: unfortunately z-index seems to be pointless

Comment: it is not pointless. its just that you are not able to crack it. If you can add a demo of your code, I can check what else is creating a problem. Maybe in https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a `position` element to `.slide` for the z-index to work properly.

> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) and flex items (elements that are direct children of display:flex elements).

You can read more on [z-index here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer for this issue. Basically you should set position and z-index for every item and set higher z-index for current active item

```css
.App .slick-slide {  
  position: relative;  
  z-index: 1; 
  /* your choice,  but make sure z-index of active slide is higher than this value */
}  
.App .slick-slide.slick-current {  
   z-index: 10;  
}
```